# Settlement/Spot/(bid ask spread) ratio

Tags: spread, liquidity, order-execution, spot-rate

Are there any studies on the average difference or ratio between Settlement (execution price) and the Spot price dependant on lot size.

I'm looking for a function such as `SETTLEMENT=SPOT*LOT_SIZE^CURVING_FACTOR/commodity_constant*ASK/BID`.

This settlement/spot ratio is dependent on the amount of liquidity and the commodity type.  However the ask/bid spread is also dependent on the amount of liquidity.  So I was hoping that the ASK/BID spread would be a good starting point.  However I don't have enough knowledge to decide what the best "curving factor" I should use, quadratic/cubic/exponentioal/linear...  Is this the correct way to model it?

I have to do this because I'll be working with a system that can't do limit/stop orders and so I need to estimate what the execution price will be *before* execution.

## Example

A 10 quantity lot transaction with a spot of 100 USD/lot could yield a settlement after execution of 1002 USD.  This is a .2% increase over the spot rate/lot.  However a 100 quantity lot transaction could yield a settlement of 1010 USD giving a 1% increase of the spot.

Comment: This will be very market-specific. The thickness of the market -- the amount of depth as you move away from the market -- will vary a lot, and will certainly be impacted by matching algorithm in use. But, in general, you are asking about "market impact" modeling. Try googling for Robert Almgren's work on it, e.g.: http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~almgren/papers/costestim.pdf